# Accessing the "Settings" of device in android

Tags: android

I want to know the path of the "Settings" present in the device. As there is a path to reach the inbox, Is there something for the Settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you need, (This is just example of change brightness of device using Setting)

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
     SysBackLightValue);
```

Look at here [Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)

This is example for opening GPS setting using system URI,

```
Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: no, i need a path like this.."content://sms/inbox/" this is for inbox i need for Settings.

Comment: so basically you are looking for some mapping where yop will get related intent/package details by its name . for this i believe you have no option then check it through document .

Comment: Thanks a lot, but actually i want to access the settings through the path and get the column present there...hence i need the path, and "Settings" is that which is present in menu of each device and contain option like "Manage application" etc. not the GPS settings.

Comment: It only for example, How can I reached at setting for gps.. you can check Android setting class for your data.